# Unable to load the request class:Curl

Tags: codeigniter, curl

I need to use curl but it throws "Unable to load the request class".

```
function p(){   
            parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('date');
        $this->load->library('curl');}
```

I load the libray in the constructor!Anyone can help me?

Comment: I think because library/class does not exist. If you have one check name spelt correct

Comment: Have you integrated library into application already?

Answer (score 1):

The cURL library is not present by default in codeigniter. You need to install the library [extension](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl) separately.